# linq to excel exception IErrorInfo.GetDescription

Tags: c#, .net, linq-to-excel

This is my code

```
    var data = new LinqToExcel.ExcelQueryFactory();
                data.FileName = @"FRM_DTA.xlsx";                
                var result = from x in data.Worksheet<ExcelFileDefinition>()
                             select x;
Console.WriteLine(result.Count());
```

I got this exception:

```
OleDbException was unhandled

IErrorInfo.GetDescription failed with E_FAIL(0x80004005).
```

on the console.write statement.

when I remove the console .write line, I got no exception

Comment: @Dalorzo I just tried your code and I got the exact same exception

Comment: Hmm, that's pretty borken error handling in that library you are using.  This is going to be a millstone around your neck if you don't address that, you don't stand much of a chance to assist your clients after your project ships.  Don't use it.

Comment: @HansPassant do you have any other alternative ?

Comment: @HansPassant it is working now. all i need the library is to read a very big excel sheet and transfer each row to a csv file and I did that now.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

The problem was the file name being incorrect. Changing that solved the problem.